# Puppet and Windows directory permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, puppet

I can't believe how difficult puppet is being with Windows - particularly windows permissions!  I have a very simple pp file that I'm trying to execute:

```
case $operatingsystem {

...

'Windows': {
        file { 'c:/puppet/':
            ensure => directory,
            owner  => 'myUser',
            group  => 'Administrators',
            mode   => '0777',
        }
    }
}
```

This seems as simple as it could get - create a directory called "c:\puppet" and let everyone have access - IT'S NOT WORKING!  It creates a directory, but nobody has ANY permissions (except special permissions).  I am in the administrators group, so I can delete it and access it, but I want to drop stuff inside and be able to install from there (since apparently an "http" source doesn't work directly on Windows ...).

Is ANYONE else using puppet for Windows, or am I just using the wrong tool for this job?  I am getting very frustrated, and the documentation seems reasonable, but without simple examples of how I'm trying to use puppet I'm getting completely stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you checked out

https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/acl
from their docs you can do something like..

```
acl { 'c:/puppet':
   permissions => [
   { identity => 'Administrator', rights => ['full'] },
   { identity => 'myuser', rights => ['read','execute'] }
   owner => 'myuser',
 ],
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this.  I'll check it out sometime soon.  Upvoting you for now for letting me know, I'll wait to accept the answer until I've had a chance to verify it.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jared have you have an opportunity to verify this? There is also a post up at http://puppetlabs.com/blog/managing-permissions-windows-access-control-lists explaining the ACL module.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution that seems to be systems administration by blunt force trauma:

```
exec { 'fix_acls':
    command => 'cmd.exe /c "takeown /r /f c:\puppet && icacls c:\puppet /grant SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F myUser:(OI)(CI)F /T"',
    path    => $::path,
}
```

This gives myUser and SYSTEM access, I could also do this with USERS in general I think, but it seems there must be a better way.